# magento 2 add unique key on multiple columns using installschema

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

Here i am trying to create unique key using `installSchema` . 
Array of column names is defined here on which columns combinedly i want to apply unique key

```
$arrayOfColumnsName = array('column1', 'column2');
```

here defined the addIndex method for creating the unique key

```
->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName(
                $installer->getTable('table_name'),
                $arrayOfColumnsName,
               \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
            $arrayOfColumnsName,
            ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        )
```

This creates unique key for only first column instead of both columns, needs help for the same

Answer (score 1):

Heading

You can use Index Type as

```
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
```

For Multiple columns:

```
->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        'table_name',
        ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    ),
    ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
);
```

For ref:

Please check vendor\magento\module-catalog\Setup\InstallSchema.php